# placing an image in the jumbotron instead of showing the video

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to get the image to show when on small screens i have managed to do this by using the code from another question however i need the image to sit in the jumbotron without stopping the video being played on screens bigger than 400-500px. would appreciate sine guidance thanks in advance. i have tried to add a code pen sadly it wont work for me. i have added a screen shot showing what happens  hope this helps.

[jum image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbwGR.jpg)

```css
body {
  margin-top: 190px;
  font-size: 2.9vmin;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4.5vmin;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 4.5vmin;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 4.5vmin;
}

.display-3 {
  font-size: 6.5vmin
}

.display-4 {
  font-size: 6.5vmin
}

.navbar {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #663735;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background: #fff;
}

.navbar .nav-item {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

img.logo {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
}

.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-size: cover;
  min-width: 0;
}

.jumbotron video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*  object-fit is not supported on IE  */
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

#jumbotron-bg {
  display: none;
}

#video video {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #video {
    display: none;
  }
  #jumbotron-bg {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">



<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <title>Law City | Home Page</title>
</head>
<section>

  <body id="home" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#main-nav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top py-0" id="main-nav">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
          <img src="LogoTransparent (1).png" class="logo">
          <h3 class="d-inline align-middle"></h3>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="Manifesto.html" class="nav-link">Manifesto</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="home-page.html" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="Opportunities.html" class="nav-link">Opportunities</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="Events.html" class="nav-link">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="Gallery.html" class="nav-link">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="Contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
</section>
<Section>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid container-fluid" style="align-items: center;">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="inner">
      <div id="video">
        <video autoplay muted loop poster="#">    
          <source src="/thecity.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="container text-white py-3">
        <h1 class="display-3">LAW CITY</h1>
        <p class="lead">Connecting future lawyers with the legal sector in the city of London</p>
        <div>
          <ul class="social_Jumbotron_ul">
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/111912483818994/posts/124800495863526/?vh=e"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="color: black;"></i></a></li>

            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/lawcity_/status/1259852447989796864?s=21"><i class="fab fa-twitter" style="color: black;"></i></a></li>


            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/posts/law-city_lawcity-legalcareer-opportunity-activity-6665618719718408194-BFNF"><i class="fab fa-linkedin" style="color: black; "></i></a></li>


            <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/CADQFm7JFhY/?igshid=a4ri79d8mpce"><i class="fab fa-instagram" style="color: black;"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="my-4">
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <div id="jumbotron-bg">
      <img src="citylon.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.jumbotron -->
</Section>
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out i managed to solve it by playing round in CSS!! yeeh!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <title>Law City | Home Page</title>
</head>
<section>
<body id="home" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#main-nav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top py-0" id="main-nav">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand" >
        <img src="LogoTransparent (1).png" class="logo">
        <h3 class="d-inline align-middle"></h3>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="Manifesto.html" class="nav-link">Manifesto</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="home-page.html" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="Opportunities.html" class="nav-link">Opportunities</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="Events.html" class="nav-link">Events</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="Gallery.html" class="nav-link">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="Contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
  <Section>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid container-fluid"  style="align-items: center;">
    <div id="jumbotron-bg"> 
        
      <img src="citylon.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="inner">
      <div id="video">
    <video autoplay muted loop poster="#">    
      <source src="/thecity.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  </div>
      <div class="container text-white py-3" >
     


    body {
  margin-top: 190px; 
    font-size: 2.9vmin;
    
 }
 h1 {
  font-size: 4.5vmin;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 4.5vmin;}

  h3 {
    font-size: 4.5vmin;}

    .display-3 {font-size: 6.5vmin}
    .display-4 {font-size: 6.5vmin}


.navbar {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #663735;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background: #fff; }
  .navbar .nav-item {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  
  
  }
  img.logo {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
}

   

  .jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:black;
  
  
  opacity:0.7;
  background-size: cover;
  min-width: 0;
}


.jumbotron video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  /*  object-fit is not supported on IE  */
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity:0.5;
}
.jumbotron .container {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}



#jumbotron-bg {
  display: none;
}
#video video{
    width:100%;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #video {
    display: none;
  }
  #jumbotron-bg {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*  object-fit is not supported on IE  */
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity:0.5;
    
  }
}
```